# Apply lefthyphenmin to parts of a word spelled with hyphens

Tags: amsmath, babel, hyphenation, german

In German, there are some words that have a single letter separated with a hyphen, for example "E-Ink-Display", "E-Auto" (electric car), "E-Mail", "x-Achse" (x-axis) and many more. When hyphenating these, the single letter must not be split up.

Is there a way (maybe with `\lefthyphenmin`) to apply this rule globally without having to use `\nobreakdash` or similar everytime such a word is used?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[american,ngerman,shorthands=off]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxx xxx xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx E-Auto
    
    should look like this:
    
    xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxx xxx xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx E\nobreakdash-Auto
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the reason for `shorthands=off`?

Comment: @egreg I use lualatex and enter specials characters directly. The quote as an active character causes too many issues with tikz, minted and other packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using `babel` with `luatex`, you can use `\babelposthyphenation`:

```
\usepackage[american,ngerman,shorthands=off]{babel}

\babelposthyphenation{ngerman}{ ^().=() }
  { {},
    { pre=-, no=-, penalty=10000 }
  }
```

See [Non–standard hyphenation with luatex](https://latex3.github.io/babel/guides/non-standard-hyphenation-with-luatex.html) for further info. Here I used the trick to limit the capture, because the `^` (word start) must be outside. It works with more or less straight texts (eg, no whatsits in the middle of a word).
`.` is any char and `=` is an explicit hyphen. Perhaps the pattern can be fine tuned and ‘any char’ is not the best option, but it can be replaced by a list of chars.

**EDIT.** Here is a better pattern:

```
\babelposthyphenation{ngerman}{ ^{A}*(){a}=() }
```

With `{A}*` we consider the possibility of leading characters like `(` or `“`, because `{A}` means ‘non-letter’ (it's the same as `%A` in lua). This part is placed before that to be processed, which is enclosed between `() ()`.

Comment: It would probably be good to replace `.` (matches "any character") with the equivalent of Lua's `%a` (match a "single alphabetical character").

Comment: @Mico Yes, indeed, or even as I said with a list of chars. To ease defining patterns without having to deal with catcodes, in this context `%a` is entered `{a}`. But I'll edit it (not right now).

Comment: This works really well and feels like the best solution to me. I just had to be careful to load `\RequirePackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}` before this command.

Answer (score 2):

Since you use LuaLaTeX, you can (a) set up a Lua function that replace all instances of `<single alphabetical character>-<letter character(s)>` with `<single alphabetical character>\nobreakdash-<letter character(s)>` and (b) assign the function to LuaTeX's `process_input_buffer` callback. That way, it'll act like a preprocessor on the input code, *before* TeX starts its usual processing.

[image]

(The framelines in the preceding screenshot are drawn by the `showframe` package.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[american,ngerman,shorthands=off]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\nobreakdash" macro

\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' environment
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function nbdash ( s ) 
  return ( s:gsub ( "(%A%a)%-(%a+)" , "%1\\nobreakdash-%2" ) ) 
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "process_input_buffer" , nbdash , "nbdash" )
```

```lua
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxx xxx xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx E-Auto
    
xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxx xxx xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx x-Achse
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use U+2011 NON-BREAKING HYPHEN

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[american,ngerman,shorthands=off]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxx xxx xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx E^^^^2011Auto

xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxx xxx xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx E‑Auto

should look like this:

xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxx xxx xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx E\nobreakdash-Auto

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to get this effect without changing every usage?